# Possible to use JavaScript or API to get the number of files in zip files

Tags: javascript, api, rest, sharepoint

We have a SharePoint site to allow users to upload attachments to document library. Sometimes they upload zip files, business area likes to know how many files are in the attached zip files.

Is there a way to achieve that through JavaScript or API?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, check out this npm module for one example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/adm-zip This is node js. I don't think it will work as client side code, but I have never used the module. But as a proof of concept, and to point you in the general direction, this might help you on your way. Notably, it has millions of downloads.

> ADM-ZIP is a pure JavaScript implementation for zip data compression for NodeJS.

```
const AdmZip = require('adm-zip');

// reading archives
const zip = new AdmZip("./my_file.zip");
const zipEntries = zip.getEntries(); // an array of ZipEntry records
const zipLength = zipEntries.length
```

Comment: Thanks for your info but we are limited to use client side code at this time. Node JS is not yet implemented.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to get files under a zip. You may have a look below JS lib:

- [zip.js](https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/)
- [JSZip API](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip.html)

And here are some demo:

- [Read a local zip file demo](https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/demos/demo-read-file.html)
- [Get a file with an ajax call](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples/get-binary-files-ajax.html)

BR

Comment: I want to get count of files in a zip file, not to get the files in zip file